# Place text above frame title in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I want to place a line of text at the top of a frame (above the frame title and default frame headline} such as:

```
\begin{frame}
    My top of frame text
    \frametitle{My title}
    My frame body
\end{frame}
```

but beamer automatically reformats.  Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Is this meant to be how you want all of your slides to be arranged or a hack for a specific slide?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I added a left-aligned `\smash`ed stack on top of the frame title.  It appears to have the same spacing as when the `\frametitle` is merely plain text.  Having a full MWE from the OP would have helped to understand if this approach is adequate.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    My top of frame text
%\frametitle{My title}
    \frametitle{\stackon{My title}{%
      \smash{\scriptsize extra text above the frame title}}}
    My frame body
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to download the stackengine package.

Comment: @guest It can be found at http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.  Putting the `.sty` file in your working directory should allow compilation, though in the long term, it should be added to your local installation directory.  Documentation is available at the site, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "native" Beamer solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myframe}[2][c]{%
    \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\hskip-.7\beamer@leftmargin\scriptsize #2\vspace*{-.2cm}}{}
    \begin{frame}[#1]%
}{%
    \end{frame}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{myframe}{text above}
\frametitle{frame title}
\end{myframe}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically this creates a custom `frame` environment which embed a patched `frametitle` template. This way you can call the `myframe` whnever you want the text above title and the default `frame` when you don't.

If needed the patching can be made global (just remove the `newenvironment`).